# How to find the volume of the largest possible solid with given properties?

Tags: calculus

A solid is described as follows.

The shadow of the solid is a circular disk when it is illuminated by rays parallel to the $z$-axis; its shadow is a square if the rays are parallel to the $y$-axis; and its shadow is an isosceles triangle if the rays are parallel to the $x$-axis. Suppose that the projection onto the $xz$-plane is a square whose sides have length 1.

What is the volume of the largest such solid? Is there a smallest volume?

I can imagine what does the solid looks like, but I have no idea how to start with this question, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the circle/cylinder is:

$x^2+z^2= 1/2$

I would try and find the volume of the triangular prism (.5) that is bounded by the cylinder above.

Comment: Oh thanks! I will try it!

Comment: I found a link showing this solid. [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorkPlug.html)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is imagine the circular disk on the xy axis and have the triangles as cross sections along dy. Then use the formula of volume by cross sections using dy and either -0.5 and 0.5 as your bounds or have your bounds from 0 to 0.5 and just multiply your final answer by 2. I'm not sure if this will find the LARGEST volume but atleast its a start.